# How do I write a shell script to issue commands and see the output on the screen

Tags: bash, shell

I want to do the following and see the commands that are issued and the result.

```
cd /WORKING_DIRECTORY
make clean
make mrproper
make VARIANT_DEFCONFIG=msm8974_sec_hlte_spr_defconfig msm8974_sec_defconfig SELINUX_DEFCONFIG=selinux_defconfig
make
```

Comment: Do you want to see it, or reproduce the results? Because `checkinstall` is a fine tool for the latter.

Comment: In bash/ksh/zsh/etc., use `set -x` to print the commands executed.

Comment: In most UNIX shells (not csh) `set -v` show the commands before expansions and substitutions, `set -x` shows the actual command executed.  `set -vx` shows both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this ...

```
#!/bin/sh
set -x
cd /WORKING_DIRECTORY
make clean
make mrproper
make VARIANT_DEFCONFIG=msm8974_sec_hlte_spr_defconfig msm8974_sec_defconfig SELINUX_DEFCONFIG=selinux_defconfig
make
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll click the accept answer as soon as the site allows me.